# Removing conda from path

Tags: bash, anaconda, fish, conda

```
echo $PATH
[OUT] /home/cmaspi/anaconda3/bin /home/cmaspi/.local/bin /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /sbin /bin /usr/games /usr/local/games /snap/bin
```

I've already removed anaconda3 directory, removed anaconda related lines from both ~/.bashrc and ~/.config/fish/config.fish

How do I get rid of anaconda from my PATH?

I've already referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585235/python-anaconda-how-to-safely-uninstall#:%7E:text=To%20uninstall%20Anaconda%20open%20a,variable%2C%20and%20remove%20the%20hidden%20.) and official [documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/).
I must add that I did the things in option A of the documentation, I didn't have the export path line that is

> export PATH="/Users/jsmith/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

in my ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile

Comment: You opened a new terminal in the mean time? With the lines removed from .profile the variable will be gone only after closing and reopening the terminal.

Comment: Yes, I did open a new terminal instance, I also rebooted system just to make sure.

Comment: Look closer: it will not necessarily be an `export` command. Could be just an assignment, i.e. `PATH=...`, normally in .profile for bash. Otherwise, you will need to see where it may be defined systemwide, e.g https://www.tecmint.com/set-unset-environment-variables-in-linux/ could be in many places.

Comment: Finally solved it, I don't entirely understand the solution. So, it's not worthy of being an answer. fish_user_paths was set at /home/cmaspi/anaconda/bin , from what i have found out, it is responsible for having some path being reflected across shells, I just cleared this variable using "$ set --erase fish_user_paths" and now things seem to be about right. Thanks to all who replied.

Comment: I must add, for me fish_user_paths just contained this anaconda path, which meant erasing the entire variable was not a problem.